# Umbraco - Create Configuration Section at runtime with config source

Tags: c#, umbraco

I'm developing an umbraco package which uses custom configuration.

My need is to create the configuration section during the intall process.

With packageActionsContrib it works fine, the code add a configSection as needed and creates a node:

```
<section name="LogServiceConfiguration" type="Utils.LogServiceConfiguration, Utils, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" allowExeDefinition="MachineToApplication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" restartOnExternalChanges="true" requirePermission="true" />

...

<LogServiceConfiguration>
    <Error EmailNodeId="0" PageUrl="" DoRedirect="false" />
  </LogServiceConfiguration>
```

What I need is to change the second part with

```
<LogServiceConfiguration configSource="config\LogService.config" />
```

I already provide the file with installation, so I have only create the line, not the file.

The code is this

```
public class AddConfigurationSection : IPackageAction
{
    #region IPackageAction Members

    public bool Execute(string packageName, XmlNode xmlData)
    {

        try
        {
            var config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
            var sectionName = xmlData.SelectSingleNode("//Section").Attributes["name"].Value;

            if (config.Sections[sectionName] == null)
            {
                var assemblyName = xmlData.SelectSingleNode("//Section").Attributes["assembly"].Value;
                var typeName = xmlData.SelectSingleNode("//Section").Attributes["type"].Value;
                var assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);

                if (assembly == null) return false;

                var configSection = assembly.CreateInstance(typeName) as ConfigurationSection;

                if (configSection == null) return false;

                config.Sections.Add(sectionName, configSection);
                configSection.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
                config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string message = "Error at execute AddConfigurationSection package action: " + e.Message;
            Log.LogException(message, e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public string Alias()
    {
        return "AddConfigurationSection";
    }

    public bool Undo(string packageName, XmlNode xmlData)
    {
        try
        {
            var config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
            var sectionName = xmlData.SelectSingleNode("//Section").Attributes["name"].Value;

            if (config.Sections[sectionName] != null)
            {

                config.Sections.Remove(sectionName);
                config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {

            return false;
        }
    }

    public XmlNode SampleXml()
    {
        var sample = "<Action runat=\"install\" undo=\"true\" alias=\"AddConfigurationSection\"><Section name=\"\" assembly=\"\" type=\"\" /></Action>";
        return helper.parseStringToXmlNode(sample);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The package action contrib project for Umbraco has a built in package action for adding configuration sections and also provides you with a way to add arbitray XML to any existing XML file like the web.config. That last example might be the most applicable to your situation, see the documentation on how to use it here:

https://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/packaging/package-actions/community-made-package-actions

Full details of the contrib project can be found here:

https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/package-actions-contrib

Comment: The first link is broken.